# Pay to upgrade phone to Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, windows-10-upgrade

Is there a site where I can post a gig to pay someone to upgrade my Nokia Lumia 1520 to Windows 10 Mobile?

I hope I'm not breaking some rules or policy here, but after a few tries, I've been unable to get it to work myself.

I've also tried to transfer Windows Phone 8 apps from one phone to another, without success.

If someone here would be interested maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can use OTC updater, it's still work for some devices like Lumia ones though Microsoft had shutdown Windows Phone 8/8.1 server. You can use this [instruction](https://handsontek.net/update-windows-phone-8-1-windows-mobile-10/).

If you encounter this problem (like i had): *"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://fe2.update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx. "* Follow this [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/all/otc-tool-server-issues-fix-here/03cc2165-71b5-4fd6-8e64-5065d2000838?auth=1).